# Visual studio slow on keyboard, keyboard lag and randomly duplicating keystrokes from keyboard input

Tags: visual-studio, performance, input, keyboard

As I type in visual studio keyboard input gets duplicated.

ex: if I type `return` it ends up `rreturn` or `retturn`

ex2: when hitting backspace it sometimes delets 2 spaces back instead of 1.

ex3: presing SHIFT + 9 should result in '`)`' but results in `'9'` as if I didn't press the SHIFT key.

Also typing is randomly slow, I type faster than characters get echoed in the editor.
This not only happens in editor but anywhere else, ie. typing something into properties, such as linker input, or just any dialog that expects keyboard input. typing lags and duplicates keystrokes.

Thing I have tried so far:

```
Tools > options > environment > automatically adjust visual experience... toggle on and off as well as 2 checkboxes below toggling on and off.
Tools > options > text editor > all languages > disable codelens
Tools > options > environment > international settings > same as MS Windows
Tools > options > source control > set to none
setting up precompiled headers
disabling all extension, run devenv in safe mode
tools > options > text editor > C/C++ > experimental > disable code analysis.
reinstalling Visual Studio and OS
```

Nothing works.

Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.9 /
Windows 10 Pro x64

all up to date, keyboard works just fine in other programs.

**Edit:**
disabling intelisense solves the problem but without it is impossible to code, are there any options to speed up intelisense? obviously the issue is intelisense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I learned What was the cause of the problem, and it's intelisense.

How to speed up intelisense...

it's that MS Defender that comes with Windows 8 and 10 is slowing down intelisense.

Adding following processes and folders to exclusion list in secrutiy center speeds up intelisense:

```
1. Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.exe
2. ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe
3. ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe
4. ServiceHub.SettingsHost.exe
5. ServiceHub.VSDetouredHost.exe
6. vcpkgsrv.exe
7. VcxprojReader.exe
8. Entry folder containing your project files
```

If you use different AV, then just put these processes to exclusion list in your AV settings.

Following are steps that can help speed up VS and intelisense:

```
Tools > options > environment > automatically adjust visual experience set to off and toggle on "enable rich client visual experience"
tools > options > text editor > C/C++ > advanced > Code analysis > disable code analysis.
Tools > options > text editor > all languages > codelens > disable codelens
Tools > options > environment > international settings > same as MS Windows
Tools > options > source control > set to none
Tools > manage extensions > disable extensions
set up precompiled headers for each project
```

**edit:**
If the above doesn't work for a long time (as was in my case) then turn off Windows defender real time protection service.
That indeed makes VS and intelisense respond instantly.

Comment: File locations: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[version]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[version]\Common7\ServiceHub\controller\Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[version]\Common7\Hosts\*

Comment: For those who struggle to find the exe files, I recommend using [voidtools everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) (way better than default windows search btw).